# Append an object inside the datatable function

Tags: jquery, datatables

Need to append an object inside the datatable function. I've the below code in multiple pages in my application. I trying to append an object to this function from a common JS file across the application.

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    lengthMenu: [
        [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
        [ '10', '25', '50', 100, 'Show all' ]
    ],
    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],
});
});
```

I tried pushing the buttons property to the DataTable function like below in the common JS file:

```
table.push({buttons: [
    {
        text:'Save as PDF',
        className: "btn btn-primary",
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        download: 'open',
    }
]
});
```

But getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Comment: Is this your exact code?  You don't have `let table=$("#table").DataTable...` or `var table=$("#table").DataTable...` ?

Comment: Where *exactly* is your `table.push` code?  Because `table` is not defined until after doc.ready, so if your push code runs before doc.ready then the `table` variable (inferred global variable) will not be defined - but that would give `table is not defined`.  So your variable exists (edit: as shown in the edit) but doesn't have a value at the time .push runs

Comment: @freedomn-m Missed to add var table; added now.

Comment: You're trying to `.push` to a variable that hasn't been given a value, so js doesn't know which "push" method to apply.   If you're using the wrong method (which I suspect) then you'll get `push is not a function`

Comment: @freedomn-m Understood. Do you know the right approach to push the buttons object from a different JS file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add editor buttons after initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58795152/2181514)   `table.button().add(...`

Comment: Thanks for the help. But getting this error: Uncaught Unknown button type: print in dataTables.buttons.min.js:19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the buttons to the `dataTable.defaults` object:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    buttons: [
        {
            text:'Save as PDF',
            className: "btn btn-primary",
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            download: 'open'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: @Hello [The documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/options#Setting-defaults) explains how to set defaults for your datatables.

Comment: @Hello [The jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) explains how the `extend` method works.

Comment: Please look into this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70248065/datatable-pdfhtml5-display-header-footer-value-in-pdf