# Datatable pdfHtml5 change header & footer value position in PDF

Tags: jquery, datatable

Im exporting PDF from the datatable using `PDFHTML5`, passing few data to the header and footer of the PDF.

Below are the few data position I want to display in the header and footer of the PDF.

```
var logo_position = obj[0].value; //top center
var date_position = obj[1].value; //bottom left
var rec_no_position = obj[2].value; // bottom middle
var page_status = obj[3].value; //bottom right
```

The above object values are getting from the database so it is based on the user selection.

I'm looking for the header & footer values in the PDF to display in the position mentioned in the variable.

**For example:**
Currently, the logo is displaying in the PDF in the top left corner. I want to display it in the center of the PDF as the `logo_position` value is top center. Same for footer also.

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    buttons: [
        {
            text:'Save as PDF',
            className: "btn btn-primary",
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            download: 'open',
            title: 'List of Records',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':not(:last-child)'
            },
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                var now = new Date();
                var jsDate = now.getDate()+'-'+(now.getMonth()+1)+'-'+now.getFullYear();
                doc['header']=(function() {
                    return {
                        columns: [
                            {
                                image: logo,
                                width: 24
                            }
                        ],
                        margin: 20
                    }
                });
                doc['footer']=(function(page, pages) {
                    return {
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: ['Printed on: ', { text: jsDate.toString() }]
                            },
                            {
                                text: [{ text: $("#page_no").text() }]
                            },
                            {
                                text: ['page ', { text: page.toString() },  ' of ', { text: pages.toString() }]
                            }
                        ],
                        margin: 20
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the reply. Can you give an idea how to achieve this?